# Listview loaded twice

Tags: listview, winjs, windows-phone-8.1

I need to set the scroll position of the user in my list view after navigating back. 
The list is inside a pivot item. To detect the scroll position I use the scroll of **.win-pivot-item-content**

```
document.querySelector(".win-pivot-item-content").onscroll = function () {
    WinJS.Application.sessionState.scrollPosition = this.scrollTop;
};
```

I use the scroll position of win-pivot-item-content because the scroll position of my listview is alwayse equals to 0...

It's a trick.. but it's working. Only if the size of the win-pivot-item is less than 15 000 px(+150 items)(why ?!)
Because after that my list load in 2 times.

```
listView.winControl.onloadingstatechanged = function () {
    // fired twice .. 
};
```

How can I force my list to load the content once ?

Edit: I started a new project based on the app template and the scroll position of the list view is also equals to 0. Is that a bug ?

Comment: check if [this](http://blog.programtheeworld.com/2013/11/15/saving-page-state-during-navigation-in-a-winjs-application/) helps

Answer (score 0):

Your list isn't loaded twice, this events is fired several times when the list is loaded.

If you want to do something when the list is fully loaded, you have to check the loading state :

```
listView.winControl.onloadingstatechanged = function (args) {
    if (ev.detail.loadingState === "complete") {
        // The code here will be called only when the list is fully loaded
    }
};
```

[This article](http://www.codefoster.com/loadingstates/) explains the differents loading states of the listview.

Note that my sample shows how to wait the end of the loading, but in the case of the scrolling, I think it can be done earlier during the loading of the list (waiting the end may cause a visual glitch when the list scrolls)